# Azure ACS is persisting the identity even after logged off

Tags: azure

I have a website which uses Azure ACS for federated authentication, which published in the cloud. Once I logged off from google provider as one gmail user and tried to loggin with other gmail credentials, the website is not providing me an option to login, it is directly accessing the previous gmail credentials and redirecting me to the gmail home page.How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to also log-off from your application. Signing out from Google will only affect if you are being redirected for log-in to Google again. 
But once authenticated with Google, you now have a `new session` in your own web site. And will be logged-in in that very `our own` website until (a) your session expires or (b) you explicitly sign out.

When using WIF/ACS, to explicitly sign out of a web application you need to execute following method:

```
var wsFedModule = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
wsFedModule.SignOut();
```

You can read more about FederatedAuthentication [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.federatedauthentication.aspx) and the specific SingOut method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh737299.aspx).

Please pay attention to the references - they are all from .NET Framework 4.5 and in `System.IdentityModel.Services` assembly, version 4.0.0.0! I strongly advice to use that framework version and assemblies, as opposite to using the .NET Framework 3.5 (4.0) and the WIF assembly `Microsoft.IdentityModel`.